# Find a specific dynamic TextBox in a C# WPF GroupBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added a GroupBox to my main Grid and am populating it dynamically with controls. I need to get a specific textbox within that GroupBox in an onClick event. I am able to loop through the GroupBox and fine, like this...

```
  foreach (Control ctl in ((Grid)gpMccEngineProperties.Content).Children)
  {
      if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
      {
          TextBox textbox = (TextBox)ctl;
          PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue();
          propertyValue.Value = textbox.Text;
      }
  }
```

... but if i just want to access a specific TextBox i keep coming back with a null value. here is how i'm trying to get it...

```
TextBox txt = ((Grid)gpMccEngineProperties.Content).Children.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => t.Name == "PropertyId_9") as TextBox;
```

... where PropertyId_9 is the name of a textbox that i added dynamically to the GroupBox. Any idea how i get that textbox so i can get it's value?

Thanks!

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML and databinding.

Comment: I have to agree with HighCore that it would be best if you did not dynamically create controls like this, and instead used proper XAML and DataBinding. However if you do want to keep this code it would help to know how your controls are created. Can you [edit] your question to include that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong Linq method. That code returns an IEnumerable of TextBoxes, not just the TextBox. Use Single or SingleOrDefault instead of Where:

```
TextBox txt = ((Grid)gpMccEngineProperties.Content).Children.OfType<TextBox>().Single(t => t.Name == "PropertyId_9");
```